# How to show the user information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am a new ASP.NET developer. I am working on a simple project and I want to show the user information from the user table in the UserProfile page. 
By the way, I am not using ASP.NET membership. 
My Query for showing the information is correct and it works fine but the problem how to give it the Username of the user to retrieve his information directly in the page.

The query is:

```
SELECT     dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, dbo.Roles.RoleName, 
                      dbo.employee.EmpOrgType
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserRole ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserRole.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Roles ON dbo.UserRole.RoleID = dbo.Roles.RoleID
WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)
```

I don't know if I should make the username a session or querystring or whatever. Could you please help me with this issue?
Also, could you please provide me with useful resources to get simple information and learn more about ASP.NET? I am using msdn website but it is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Do you really mean to say you identify the User from his name, the additional thing then in this query would be to check in the same **case**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly retrieve the information to your page you should declare variable to retrieve the user identity and others informations if you need it. So I think you can post your ASPX code so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in diffirent ways.

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

And you can learn more on ASP.net here:

[ASP.NET](http://ASP.Net)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be storing the Username in session and retriving the name from the session to show the user's profile details.

Answer (score 0):

For your user to get to his profile page he needs to be logged in. So if you made your own login system one way to keep track of the user is to store his username/password in session. Then when you query you can get the correct employee by accessing the session variable.

With the membership system already being built in i'm not sure why you rolled your own.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your authentication mechanism.

If you are using Forms based authentication, in the login page after you authenticate the user, add the username to a session variable, then pass it on to the stored proc.

If you are relying on windows based authentication. System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name will give the username.